# Pandas - Fillna or where function based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column `indicator` that takes the value of `code`. I cannot use if else statements, because `code` can have a value and the same value somewhere else in the column of `second code`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-04-19','2019-04-20','2019-05-03', '2019-05-04',
             '2019-10-01','2019-10-07','2019-10-11', '2019-11-20'],
    'category': ['ID F', 'ID F', 'ID F', 'ID F',
             'ID B', 'ID B', 'ID B', 'ID B'],
    'code': ['None', 'None', 'None', '8008',
             'None', 'None', '9001', 'None'],
    'second_code': ['None', 'None', '8008', 'None',
             'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)


date    category    code    second_code
0   2019-04-19  ID F    None    None
1   2019-04-20  ID F    None    None
2   2019-05-03  ID F    None    8008
3   2019-05-04  ID F    8008    None
4   2019-10-01  ID B    None    None
5   2019-10-07  ID B    None    None
6   2019-10-11  ID B    9001    None
7   2019-11-20  ID B    None    None
```

Desired DataFrame

```
date    category       code    second_code indicator
0   2019-04-19  ID F    None    None    None
1   2019-04-20  ID F    None    None    None
2   2019-05-03  ID F    None    8008    8008
3   2019-05-04  ID F    8008    None    None
4   2019-10-01  ID B    None    None    None
5   2019-10-07  ID B    None    None    None
6   2019-10-11  ID B    9001    None    9001
7   2019-11-20  ID B    None    None    None
```

Edit:

I have tried:

```
df['indicator'] = np.where(df['new_code'].notnull(), df['new_code'], np.where(df['code']).notnull(), df['code'], np.nan)
```

but am getting the error  `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'notna'`

Comment: Why is your line `3` have indicator `None`?

Comment: seems like fillna problem

Comment: @QuangHoang because this value has been shifted from the other column (i.e. it is actually associated with 2019-05-03 not 2019-05-04)

Comment: How can you tell when to bring second code vs code in your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way should be to use the `fillna` function along with the `drop_duplicates` to ensure we get the first time a specific code shows up in the column.

```
# First we need to replace the "None" with actual NaN values
df = df.replace("None", np.nan)

df["indicator"] = df["second_code"].fillna(df["code"]).drop_duplicates()

df
        date category  code second_code indicator
0 2019-04-19     ID F   NaN         NaN       NaN
1 2019-04-20     ID F   NaN         NaN       NaN
2 2019-05-03     ID F   NaN        8008      8008
3 2019-05-04     ID F  8008         NaN       NaN
4 2019-10-01     ID B   NaN         NaN       NaN
5 2019-10-07     ID B   NaN         NaN       NaN
6 2019-10-11     ID B  9001         NaN      9001
7 2019-11-20     ID B   NaN         NaN       NaN
```

Essentially I'm telling pandas to: take the column "second_code," and fill in any missing values (NaN) in "second_code" with the values from "code". Then, get rid of any potential duplicate entries from the aforementioned operation and assign this result to the "indicator" column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2019-04-19','2019-04-20','2019-05-03', '2019-05-04',
             '2019-10-01','2019-10-07','2019-10-11', '2019-11-20'],
    'category': ['ID F', 'ID F', 'ID F', 'ID F',
             'ID B', 'ID B', 'ID B', 'ID B'],
    'code': ['None', 'None', 'None', '8008',
             'None', 'None', '9001', 'None'],
    'second_code': ['None', 'None', '8008', 'None',
             'None', 'None', 'None', 'None']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)

df['indicator'] = df['code']

print(df)
```

output.

```
        date category  code second_code indicator
0 2019-04-19     ID F  None        None      None
1 2019-04-20     ID F  None        None      None
2 2019-05-03     ID F  None        8008      None
3 2019-05-04     ID F  8008        None      8008
4 2019-10-01     ID B  None        None      None
5 2019-10-07     ID B  None        None      None
6 2019-10-11     ID B  9001        None      9001
7 2019-11-20     ID B  None        None      None
```

Read more here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html, the documentation has everything.

Comment: this is incorrect - please look at rows 2:3 in the desired dataframe in the question.